# Google maps api v2, on marker click to open a fragment on the map

Tags: android, android-fragments, maps, overlay

**What I want to realise:**

I want my markers, that are clickable, to open a fragment on top of the map when I'm in their proximity.
This fragment will list some text and pictures.
I want this fragment to overlay only a part of the googlemap and to be closeable.

I already have some basic info in the 'snippet'-thingy that opens one click.
I also have a function that calculates the distance from the middle of the screen to a location and puts it in the snippet.

some code I have:

```
    simLocatie.setLatitude((googlemap.getCameraPosition().target).latitude);
    simLocatie.setLongitude((googlemap.getCameraPosition().target).longitude);

    googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                  .title(een.getName())                                                    
                  .position(new LatLng(een.getLatitude(),een.getLongitude()))                                                       
                  .snippet("distance:"+simLocatie.distance(een))                                           
               .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_monument)));
```

Thanks in advance!
if I didn't explain myself good enough please ask for more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> implement OnMarkerClickListener

and use this method: (it will be called when u click on a marker)

```
@Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        return false;
    }
```

inside this function open your fragment.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have unique data for every marker on your map.

When you fetch markers data from internet or locally, you should save them into HashMap.

```
HashMap<Marker, String> map=new HashMap<Marker, String>();
for(MarkerInfo t : fetchedMarkerArray){
    /* add your markers to map, and everything what you need*/
}
```

When you need to access to data you can easily do that by ( like Daan said you should implement OnMarkerClickListener):

```
onMarkerClick(Marker marker){
    MarkerInfo m = (MarkerInfo)map.get(marker);
    //show your fragment with data
}
```

If you have any additional questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Yeah we're getting information for the different locations(markers) from a local database, I was thinking to put them all in an ArrayList and to fetch them with their indexes. thx for the reply!

Comment: It's easier for you to save data into HashMap because of fetching them later. Anyway you will must to save your indexes into map because Marker class is final.